# How to iterate simple cycles in ascending cycle length order?

Tags: python, graph-theory, graph-tool, cycle-detection

I want to find all nodes of a graph, which are in simple cycles of length up to some given maximum cycle length `max_length`. Along with this I want to make a histogram of the number of cycles (per cycle length) that each node is contained in. I'm trying to figure out what the best way is to get this task done.

Related question:
[For a given node, how to find small cycles of which that node is a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77686557/for-a-given-node-how-to-find-small-cycles-of-which-that-node-is-a-member) is a related question which is more specific than this question here. They are not duplicates.

I'm using python and [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) for analysing the graph, which seems to be a good choice, because several tests indicate that graph-tool is among the world's top performance graph libraries, esp. for python. I prefer to use python for this. In particular, others were not fast enough (networkx) or had bad time complexity (edge deletion in igraph) and hence didn't scale for other tasks for what I need them.

Here are my ideas for approaches:

Idea 1:
Iterate over all cycles of the graph in the order of ascending cycle length and take note of the nodes therein.

Idea 1.1. (Following up Idea 1.):
There is the function [`graph_tool.topology.all_circuits`](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/autosummary/graph_tool.topology.all_circuits.html), but that doesn't seem to iterate over only simple cycles or not in the order that I want. I don't really know what it does exactly. I just know that I can't use it, because it has exploding time complexity with my graph. E.g. for the small [Zachary's karate club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zachary%27s_karate_club) with just 34 nodes, it finds 1462130 many cycles. I want to analyse graphs with about 2 million nodes and 4 million edges. I've tried to run [`graph_tool.topology.all_circuits`](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/autosummary/graph_tool.topology.all_circuits.html) for such a graph, but this way I didn't even get to see many of the shorter cycles that I'm interested in. I estimate that the cycle search on graphs like the ones I want to analyse would run for several years using this approach. Illustration:

```
import graph_tool.collection
import graph_tool.topology

g = graph_tool.collection.data["karate"]

print("number of nodes in graph:", g.num_vertices())

print()
print(f"circ_idx\tcircuit")
circuit_iter = graph_tool.topology.all_circuits(g)
i = 0
for circuit in circuit_iter:
    i += 1
    if i % 152371 == 0:
        print(f"{i}\t{circuit}")

print("total number of circuits:", i)
```

Output:

```
number of nodes in graph: 34

circ_idx        circuit
152371  [ 0  3  1 13  2 28 31 25 24 27 33 29 23 32  8]
304742  [ 0  7  1 30 32 23 33 27 24 25 31 28  2  3 12]
457113  [ 0  8 30  1 19 33 18 32 29 23 25 24 31]
609484  [ 0  8 33 27 24 25 23 29 32  2  3]
761855  [ 0 13  1  7  3  2 32 31 25 23 33 19]
914226  [ 0 17  1  7  3  2 32 31 24 27 23 29 33 30  8]
1066597 [ 0 19 33 27 24 25 23 29 32 30  1  3]
1218968 [ 0 31 24 27 23 29 26 33 22 32  2  3 12]
1371339 [ 0 31 32 23 25 24 27 33 13  3  2  1 30  8]
total number of circuits: 1462130
```

Idea 1.2. (Following up Idea 1.):
Implement Idea 1. myself. Doable, but this sounds like quite some work. I don't want to invent the wheel another time. Is there a better way?

Idea 2:
As an alternative to Idea 1., it's also okay to iterate per node over the cycles that a given node is contained in, again in the order of ascending cycle lengths. This can be done with a breadth first search (BFS), starting from the node in question.
With this I can then check membership of a node in said cycles and then move on to the next node. This is less efficient, because I will process cycles repeatedly for every node that is contained in the same cycle, but it will still give reasonable overall time complexity.
The big advantage of this approach is that the implementation will be easier than Idea 1.

Are there better approaches? Does graph-tool offer something that is more well suited for this task?

Comment: Maybe this function is what you want? https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.chordless_cycles.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.chordless_cycles There's parameter `length_bound` which limits the cycles size.

Comment: @AndrejKesely thanks for the suggestion, but networkx, which is a pure python implementation based on python dicts, is simply too slow for the large graphs that I want to process.

Comment: You can edit your question and put there how big is your graph, perhaps a small sample input and what performance you want etc.

Comment: I do not fully understand what you are asking.  Perhaps you could clarify your question?  There are two steps: 1. Finding the cycles and 2. Analyzing the output from a cycle finder.   It seems like you may have a solution for step 1, but I am not sure.  Step 2, analyzing the output from a cycle finder seems to be a fairly trivial task: discard the cycles that are too long, then iterate over the nodes checking how many cycles they are in.  In general, your question seems to revolve around performance, so you should provide your performance requirement and the performance you have now.

Comment: Note: " not fast enough" is not a performance requirement.  You need to specify how large the graphs are to be and the maximum calculation time you can accept.  Ideally, a reference graph ( or 5  ) to run performance tests on are needed.

Comment: @ravenspoint I've added information about real graph sizes that I want to analyse and preliminary results. I've now also given the example with 34 nodes and 1462130 cycles, which makes the point more than clear.

Comment: Neat example data set. Thanks. What is your performance requirement for running this dataset

Comment: @ravenspoint running in less than 1 min, ideally in just a few seconds, for a connected graph with 2M nodes and 4M edges, i.e. 2M+ cycles. With all_circuits, it didn't even find many relevant cycles within many minutes. And it didn't even find all cycles for a single node within that time. But there are millions of nodes for which I want to run it. I.e. it's just not a suitable algorithm for this problem.

Comment: What is your performance requirement for running the Zachary dataset?

Comment: @ravenspoint I don't have a performance requirement for the Zachary graph, because this is not a graph I want to analyse practically.

Comment: If you do not have a performance requirement for the dataset you have provided as an example then your question is unanswerable.  There is no way to tell whether or not my code can meet your requirement.

Comment: @ravenspoint, I can give you something else instead, which is better suited. The usability of the algorithm depends on the time complexity of the algorithm in the end. It needs to run in O(|V|) with |V| being the number of nodes, given a `max_length` of the cycles, which with my graphs implies an upper bound in number of nodes that need to be visited for a particular node's cycles, because the average node degrees in my graphs is about just 4 with minor deviations. This is called a [parameterized complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity).

Answer (score 2):

> There is the function `graph_tool.topology.all_circuits`, but that doesn't seem to iterate over only simple cycles or not in the order that I want. I don't really know what it does exactly. I just know that I can't use it, because it has exploding time complexity with my graph. E.g. for the small Zachary's karate club with just 34 nodes, it finds `1462130` many cycles.

Note that `graph-tool` and `networkx` agree on the total count of simple cycles in the karate club graph.

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.karate_club_graph()
g = nx.DiGraph(g)
cycles = nx.simple_cycles(g)
num_cycles = sum(1 for c in cycles)
```

That snippet takes ~1 minute to run and counts `1462130` cycles (same as graph-tool).

> I want to analyse graphs with about 2 million nodes and 4 million edges. I've tried to run graph_tool.topology.all_circuits for such a graph, but this way I didn't even get to see many of the shorter cycles that I'm interested in. I estimate that the cycle search on graphs like the ones I want to analyse would run for several years using this approach.

It seems clear that finding *all* simple cycles is out of the question, then.

> Idea 2:
> As an alternative to Idea 1., it's also okay to iterate per node over the cycles that a given node is contained in, again in the order of ascending cycle lengths. This can be done with a breadth first search (BFS), starting from the node in question.

If you don't need to count cycles above some length `N`, then a custom search (either BFS or DFS) may be your only option.  Although `graph-tool` does contain tools for customizing a BFS/DFS search via "visitors", you won't benefit from C++ speed, since the visitor will have to call python functions for each edge/node visited.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some C++ code that builds a histogram of the number of cycles each node in a graph belongs to.

This uses the depth first search cycle finder in the the PathFinder graph theory library.  https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder

Processing the Zachary test data set requires 4 milliseconds to find the 42 cycles under or equal length to 5, while building the histogram takes 2 microseconds.

Here is the main code:

```
void findCycles()
{
    raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("findCycles");

    /* find cycles in graph
    using modified depth first search
    in PathFinder graph theory library
    https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder
    */
   
    vCycle = dfs_cycle_finder(gd);

}
void histogram()
{
    raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("histogram");

    nodeCycleCount.resize(gd.g.vertexCount());
    for (auto &vc : vCycle)
    {
        for (int v : vc)
        {
            nodeCycleCount[v]++;
        }
    }
}

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    raven::set::cRunWatch::Start();

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    read(argv[1]);

    findCycles();

    std::cout << vCycle.size() << " cycles found\n";

    histogram();

    std::cout << "Node\tCycles\n";
    for (int n = 0; n < nodeCycleCount.size(); n++)
    {
        std::cout << gd.g.userName(n) << "\t" << nodeCycleCount[n] << "\n";
    }

    raven::set::cRunWatch::Report();

    return 0;
}
```

The complete application code is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/so77686189

Here is the output:

```
42 cycles found
Node    Cycles
3       17
1       21
2       10
4       7
5       2
6       4
7       4
8       3
9       4
10      1
11      2
12      0
13      1
14      6
17      1
18      1
20      3
22      2
26      3
24      5
25      3
28      3
29      2
30      4
27      1
31      5
32      9
33      24
15      1
16      1
19      1
21      1
23      1
34      25
raven::set::cRunWatch code timing profile
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
       1        0.0035151       0.0035151       findCycles
       1        2e-06   2e-06   histogram
```