# For a given node, how to find small cycles of which that node is a member?

Tags: python, graph-theory, graph-tool, cycle-detection

I'm using python and [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) to do graph analysis. In a graph `g`, I want to find all cycles up to a specific length `max_length` of which a given node `node` is a member.

Related question:
[How to iterate simple cycles in ascending cycle length order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77686189/how-to-iterate-simple-cycles-in-ascending-cycle-length-order) is a broader question, which is more general and about a broader aspect. These questions act on different levels of abstraction and they are not duplicates of each other.

I've tried [`graph_tool.topology.all_circuits`](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/autosummary/graph_tool.topology.all_circuits.html), but that runs far too long. It finds way too many cycles, e.g. for a [graph with just 34 nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zachary%27s_karate_club), it finds 1462130 many cycles. In practice, I want to analyse a graph with more than 2 million nodes and there it would probably run for years. Here is an example to test this:

```
import graph_tool.collection
import graph_tool.topology

g = graph_tool.collection.data["karate"]

print("number of nodes in graph:", g.num_vertices())

print()
print(f"circ_idx\tcircuit")
circuit_iter = graph_tool.topology.all_circuits(g)
i = 0
for circuit in circuit_iter:
    i += 1
    if i % 152371 == 0:
        print(f"{i}\t{circuit}")

print("total number of circuits:", i)
```

Output:

```
number of nodes in graph: 34

circ_idx        circuit
152371  [ 0  3  1 13  2 28 31 25 24 27 33 29 23 32  8]
304742  [ 0  7  1 30 32 23 33 27 24 25 31 28  2  3 12]
457113  [ 0  8 30  1 19 33 18 32 29 23 25 24 31]
609484  [ 0  8 33 27 24 25 23 29 32  2  3]
761855  [ 0 13  1  7  3  2 32 31 25 23 33 19]
914226  [ 0 17  1  7  3  2 32 31 24 27 23 29 33 30  8]
1066597 [ 0 19 33 27 24 25 23 29 32 30  1  3]
1218968 [ 0 31 24 27 23 29 26 33 22 32  2  3 12]
1371339 [ 0 31 32 23 25 24 27 33 13  3  2  1 30  8]
total number of circuits: 1462130
```

Therefore, I think that the best approach is to use breadth first search (BFS), starting at node `node`, to find the cycles up to a specific length of which this node is a member, and stopping the BFS when the `max_length` is reached. I've tried that using [graph_tool.search.bfs_iterator](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/autosummary/graph_tool.search.bfs_iterator.html) and [graph_tool.search.bfs_search](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/autosummary/graph_tool.search.bfs_search.html), but surprisingly, neither of them can be used to find cycles at all, as can be seen from the output of the following program:

```
import graph_tool.collection
import graph_tool.search

g = graph_tool.collection.data["karate"]
print("number of nodes in graph:", g.num_vertices())

print()
print("adjacencies")
for src in range(5):
    neighbors_list = g.get_all_neighbors(src)
    neighbors_list.sort()
    print("   ", src, neighbors_list)
print("    ...")

node = 0

print()
print("graph_tool.search.bfs_iterator")
bfs_iter = graph_tool.search.bfs_iterator(g, node)
for edge in bfs_iter:
    src = g.vertex_index[edge.source()]
    tar = g.vertex_index[edge.target()]
    found = "   ############################## cycle found!!!" if tar == node else "   no cycle found"
    print("   ", src, tar, found)
```

Output:

```
number of nodes in graph: 34

adjacencies
    0 [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10 11 12 13 17 19 21 31]
    1 [ 0  2  3  7 13 17 19 21 30]
    2 [ 0  1  3  7  8  9 13 27 28 32]
    3 [ 0  1  2  7 12 13]
    4 [ 0  6 10]
    ...

graph_tool.search.bfs_iterator
    0 1    no cycle found
    0 2    no cycle found
    0 3    no cycle found
    0 4    no cycle found
    0 5    no cycle found
    0 6    no cycle found
    0 7    no cycle found
    0 8    no cycle found
    0 10    no cycle found
    0 11    no cycle found
    0 12    no cycle found
    0 13    no cycle found
    0 17    no cycle found
    0 19    no cycle found
    0 21    no cycle found
    0 31    no cycle found
    1 30    no cycle found
    2 9    no cycle found
    2 27    no cycle found
    2 28    no cycle found
    2 32    no cycle found
    5 16    no cycle found
    8 33    no cycle found
    31 24    no cycle found
    31 25    no cycle found
    27 23    no cycle found
    32 14    no cycle found
    32 15    no cycle found
    32 18    no cycle found
    32 20    no cycle found
    32 22    no cycle found
    32 29    no cycle found
    33 26    no cycle found
```

The [graph_tool.search.bfs_search](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/autosummary/graph_tool.search.bfs_search.html) together with a [BFSVisitor](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/autosummary/graph_tool.search.BFSVisitor.html) is another approach to BFS, but it has the same obstacle for detecting cycles, and it is thus unusable for my purpose. (Update: I doubt my own assessment here. See comment.)

Do I really have to implement BFS on my own in order to use a BFS for cycle detection? It's not tons of work, but I wonder if there is a better alternative. Moreover, implementing it in python will make it slow.

Comment: Maybe [graph_tool.search.BFSVisitor.non_tree_edge](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/autosummary/graph_tool.search.BFSVisitor.html#graph_tool.search.BFSVisitor.non_tree_edge) is helpful for using the built-in BFS for cycle detection. I had overlooked it up until to now.

Comment: When you have decided what the question is that you actually want to ask, then I will take another look.  For now, you keep dodging my questions and changing things around far too quickly for me to keep up.

Comment: @ravenspoint don't worry about my questions, I don't need your answers. Just go elsewhere. Thank you.

Comment: I'll just give two pieces of advice and then I'll be on my way: (1) To find cycles of `max_length`, you don't need to run the BFS up to `max_length`, you only need to run them up to `max_length // 2` (that can be an exponential improvement). (2) When people are trying to be helpful, it is often more productive to try to keep an open mind, question yourself and reassess your issue, rather than respond with hostility.

Comment: I haven't used the `graph-tool` library, but if you're looking for something built-in,  it looks like [`graph_tool.topology.all_paths`](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/autosummary/graph_tool.topology.all_paths.html#graph_tool.topology.all_paths) has a `cutoff` parameter to specify the max path length. You should be able to get cycles by setting `source` and `target` to the same node.

Comment: @Stef, thanks for the hints. Well, for your second hint, yes, if they actually try to be helpful, absolutely! For example ravenspoint's comment here is absolutely not helpful.

Comment: @beaker thank you, your suggestion with the `cutoff` was crucial. I was able to use it to find all cycles of lengths up to a given maximum length. It has reasonably good performance. I currently use your suggestion with a modification: To find the cycles containing a given node v, I first get all neighbors of v and then find all paths from v to each of its neighbors, ignoring all paths of length 1. This way i can reduce the `cutoff` by 1 and gain, for my purposes, another speedup of about 5x to 10x (will differ for other graphs). It's still not the optimal solution, but it works for me.

Comment: @DanielS. Ah, clever modification. You should post that as an answer for future visitors. And yes, using the built-in DFS was never going to be the fastest, but as long as it's *fast enough*, that's all that matters.